# data bind nested json data using knockout from web api asp.net mvc

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

Im trying to data bind some nested json from a web api call. Do I need to create another observable for the nested data or does knockout look after that. I have a job object returning from the api that job has a job list. I want to bind the jobId and the joblistID. im just looking for a simple way to do this    json code

```
[
    {
        "$id":"1",
        "JobID":1,
        "JobsListID":1,
        "BookingID":1,
        "TimeAllowed":20,
        "TimeTaken":22,
        "Comments":"Some comments",
        "Status":"complete",
        "Notes":null,
        "TimeStarted":"2014-11-04T09:00:00",
        "Difficulty":1,
        "CompleteDate":"2014-11-04T09:22:00",
        "booking":null,
        "jobs_mechanics":[],
        "jobslist": {
            "$id":"2",
            "JobsListID":1,
            "JobCategoryID":1,
            "Description":"Change Tyres",
            "Name":"Tyres",
            "jobs": [
                {"$ref":"1"}
            ],
            "jobscategory":null,
            "model_jobslist":[]
        },
        "timessheets":[]
    }
]
```

html

```
                      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
          <tr>
      <th>Job ID</th>
           <th>JobList ID</th>

     </tr>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Jobs">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: JobID"></td>
    </tr>
```

joblist id or name or anything from the
                                 joblist to go here just to
                                    understand how to display nested data

```
                  </td>
               </tr>
             </table>



  script code 
           <script>
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Jobs = ko.observableArray();
    self.error = ko.observable();


    var JobsApi = 'http://localhost:54155/api/mechanicphone';

    function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
        self.error(''); // Clear error message
        return $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: uri,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.error(errorThrown);
        });
    }
    function getAllJobs() {
        ajaxHelper(JobsApi, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            self.Jobs(data);
        });
    }

    getAllJobs();


};


ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: So you only want to show the job id and each job list id? Can you please post what you want the table to look like?

Comment: ive edited it im more concerned how to data bind the nested data rather how it looks just to get it dislplayed. so I understand how to do it

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in the console output of your browser? It looks like the callback of your ajaxHelper method is passing in the entire jobs object to self.Jobs instead of the list. Might try: self.Jobs(data.jobslist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would simply just use a `foreach` and then to get the joblistId use `jobslist.JobsListID` like so:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Job ID</th>
            <th>JobList ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Jobs">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: JobID"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: jobslist.JobsListID"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1mkfudyg/)

Comment: thank you, it worked I actually tried that before and just realised I left the s out in jobslist

Comment: is it possible to call the function getAllJobs() from a button click I tried <button data-bind="click: getAllJobs()" class="btn btn-danger" >Get Jobs</button> it says getAllJobs not definded

Comment: You need to add the getAllJobs to the viewmodel like so: `self.getAllJobs = function () { ... }`. At the moment it's scoped to only inside the viewmodel and not exposed publicly.